# pyspark job to existing context

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-jobserver

I'm wondering how to go about submitting spark "jobs" to a single application (allowing for sharing of RDD work but also code/execution independence of modules). I've seen this [spark-jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) formally at ooyala, but I noticed it doesn't yet support python. Is this the common route taken for this use case in scala/java? Or am I going down the wrong route here?

I've also seen a less popular [pyspark-jobserver](https://github.com/boazjohn/pyspark-job-server) and open issues on the main spark-jobserver to address python and R.

In order to have a better understanding of the use case of spark-jobserver, I'm also wondering why this functionality wouldn't be supported directly by spark given their detailed job-scheduling framework.

Comment: Python is not supported by spark-jobserver yet.

Comment: I believe I mentioned that in my question! I'm hoping for an answer that at least discusses whether this is the right direction.

Comment: In the comment you mentioned about ooyala spark-jobserver (https://github.com/ooyala/spark-jobserver) which is no longer the maintained version. The maintained version is located at https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver. Also I have not answered your question, I was asserting that python support is not their yet in spark-jobserver. This thread got my attention because it has spark-jobserver tag. It doesn't look like a spark-jobserver question, as you already know python is not supported by it. And your question is specific to why spark is not supporting what you want.

Comment: I did not link to ooyala, and merely specified it was migrated from there. I also already asserted "but I noticed it doesn't yet support python". The reason I tagged spark-jobserver is because I want to learn more about its general use case, and whether or not it makes sense as a future direction for my desired use case. I had a side question to why it isn't directly supported by Spark because I want to have a better understanding of the spark-job-server's use case. I'll edit to make it more clear.